# I need help on how to start developing an iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I have been programming in Microsoft Dot net for the past 4 years. Now, I want to develop an iPhone application. I have no idea where to start. I do not know anything about MAC OSX or any other Apple "words":). Searches on the google about books and online articles fetch a lot of results which is confusing. It would be great if anybody can share their beginner's experience. Thank You.

Comment: 1. Get a Mac 2. Install Xcode 3. Start programming

Comment: @roryf - You make the first step sound trivial.

Comment: @derekerdmann 1. Go to http://store.apple.com 2. Enter Credit Card details 3. Wait for delivery man

Comment: @roryf - 0. Acquire currency.  That's the tough part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto articles for iPhone development, Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development

Answer (score 1):

I've learn all about iPhone programming with this great book: [Beginning iPhone 3 Development](http://www.iphonedevbook.com/).

Comment: This book looks like a great start. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it surprisingly easy to pick up. The Apple dev center includes a lot of sample code, and because it's the programming language du jour, there's a lot of forum links and StackOverflow questions about it, as well as plenty of people looking to answer new questions.

It's pretty satisfying to do too, if you've never done mobile development before.

Get yourself a machine and download XCode, the supplied Apple IDE. It's a bit lamer than Eclipse right now, but the new version which is on the verge of release looks much better. Grab yourself access to the developer center (which is worth the investment) and build a simple App or two. Get to know Interface Builder first, because you may not have worked with things like this before.

There are some idiosyncracies in the syntax and whatnot, but you get used to it pretty fast. And then come here and ask more questions. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Yeah, will surely have many more questions:)

Comment: Is there a way to develop iPhone applications in a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran through [this tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2009/01/15/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-1/) to get familiar with XCode and Interface Builder.

Then joining a local group about it should be helpful - I'm a member of the Iphone London Users Group and chats with other developers is the most useful tool I have to find out how to do things.